# How can I find the form ID of a form?

Tags: forms

How do I get the form id of my form? I've just begun to make my modules and I'm at a standstill. I got this code from someone else and am trying to customize it:

```
function hook_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id == 'the form id for the node form') {
    $form['#submit'][] = 'my_custom_submit_handler';
  }
}
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try printing the form variables with PHP function [print_r](http://php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php).

```
function hook_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  print_r($form);
}
```

When you visit the page the form is on, the variables (and name) will be displayed.

An easier way of accessing (or rather viewing) the information would be using [dpm()](http://api.lullabot.com/dpm) function provided by the [Devel module](http://drupal.org/project/devel). You can use it in the same way you would use print_r.

Comment: Given the reported code, there is no need to see the content of the `$form` variable.

Comment: Also $form_id is a param you can directly print it !!

Comment: If you have [Devel](https://www.drupal.org/project/devel) enabled, just `dpm($form_id);`

Answer (score 42):

### Finding FORM ID without installing module

**Finding the Form ID is very easy** **no need to install modules** and all

**STEP 1:** Open you from go to its edit page(OR inspect your form).

**STEP 2:** if its a **node form** find "**node-form**" in the inspect element

[image: Finding the form id] check you are in the **form** element.

**STEP 3:** see attached image the **highlighted green** text is the ID of the form

**STEP 4: IMPORTANT** Finally if you want to use it in `hook_form_alter()` replace the **hypen** with **underscore**

For example: `yourform_id_with_content_type_name_form`

Like wise you can find id of any form in drupal all you have to do is inspect->find form element and search for the ID attribute and use it

Hope it helps :)

Comment: This didn't work for me when I wanted to protect the comment form in a Drupal 8 site. I found a solution in [this comment on drupal.org](https://www.drupal.org/project/captcha/issues/2674288#comment-11174249), where it says: 1) Find a hidden input element whose `name` attribute has value "form_id". 2) Look at the input element's `value` attribute - the attribute's value is the desired form ID. Example: The comment form on story nodes has the form ID "comment_comment_node_story_form". If you like you can incorporate this new information in your answer.

Comment: sometime the id changes depending on the context. niksmak suggestion is a better approach

Answer (score 10):

If your webform is located at "www.mydomain.com/node/351" then your form ID will be "webform_client_form_351". So, whatever your nid is - that's your form ID.

Comment: The question is not about the Webform module. It is about the node edit form.

Comment: The question is about the node edit form but if you want to find any webform form ID this works correcty.

Comment: This answer is right, just tested it.

Answer (score 6):

If you know where the code is that defines the form you want to alter, look there. The form id is just the name of the function defining that form.

For example, Views defines the function views_ui_edit_view_form on line 875 of views/includes/admin.inc. The Hierarchical Select views filter looks for that form id on line 50 of hierarchical_select/modules/hs_taxonomy_views.module in a hood_form_alter function.

Answer (score 5):

Use `drupal_set_message()` function to display the form id.

```
function hook_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id) {
drupal_set_message($form_id);
// other codes
}
```

Comment: `drupal_set_message($form_id);` is deprecated in Drupal 10. You can use `\Drupal::messenger()->addMessage($form_id);` instead.

Answer (score 4):

Use the [Get Form ID](https://www.drupal.org/project/get_form_id) module to easily find out form id of any form in Drupal.

Here is a quote about it from its project page:

> By hovering over any form you will see a contextual link available. By expanding the link you will see the form ID. Click on the link and you will see a modal window with copyable form id and hook_form_FORM_ID_alter() hook suggestion.
>
> This module is deprecated. It was improved, extended and rebranded as [Devel form debug](https://www.drupal.org/project/devel_form_debug); use it instead.

Disclosure: I'm maintainer of these modules.

Answer (score 3):

As the code you reported is looking for the form ID of the node form, there are two cases.

#### Drupal 6

If the code is trying to alter the form used to set the settings for a content type, then it should use the following IF-statement.

```
if ($form_id == 'node_type_form' && isset($form['identity']['type'])) { /* … */ }
```

If the code is trying to alter the node edit form, then the code should use the following IF-statement.

```
if (isset($form['type']) && isset($form['#node']) && $form['type']['#value'] . '_node_form' == $form_id) { /* … */ }
```

#### Drupal 7 and higher

In the first case, the IF-statement should be the following one:

```
if ($form_id == 'node_type_form') { /* … */ }
```

Using a different approach, supposing that mymodule is the short name of your module, you could use `mymodule_form_node_type_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id)`. Since Drupal 7, all the hooks used to alter the form implemented by another module gets `$form_id` as last parameter. See [hook_form_alter()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7), [hook_form_FORM_ID_alter()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.api.php/function/hook_form_FORM_ID_alter/7), [hook_form_BASE_FORM_ID_alter()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.api.php/function/hook_form_BASE_FORM_ID_alter/7).

In the second case, the IF-statement is the same used for Drupal 6.

```
if (isset($form['type']) && isset($form['#node']) && $form['type']['#value'] . '_node_form' == $form_id) { /* … */ }
```

Answer (score 2):

First install [Devel module](https://www.drupal.org/project/devel).Then create a module like the code below

```
function hook_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  dpm($form);
}
```

Then you can see ALL details of a form, like form ID, field names of a form etc.

Answer (score 0):

In Drupal 8 you can get a form id like this.
You have to write this code in your `.module` file

```
function modulename_form_alter(&$form, \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id){
  echo "my form id is : ".$form_id;
}
```