# Adding CSS and JS to form with attachments

Tags: 7, forms

I need to add some external and local CSS and JavaScript files to a form, but I can't seem to find the right way to do this.  Do I simply add the paths and URLs for the JS and CSS files?

I assume `$form['#attached']['css'][]` and `$form['#attached']['js'][]` are the correct places to do this, so they get reloaded on form rebuilds.  I seem to be missing something.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

Have you looked at the documentation?

**Attach CSS and JS to form**

http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7#attached

```
$form['#attached']['css'][] = drupal_get_path('module', 'ajax_example') . '/ajax_example.css';

$form['#attached']['js'][] = drupal_get_path('module', 'ajax_example') . '/ajax_example.js';
```

**External files**

http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/drupal_process_attached/7

External 'js' and 'css' files can also be loaded. For example:

```
$build['#attached']['js']['http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.2.min.js'] = array('type' => 'external');
```

Comment: I have.  Can you tell me where it references how to handle external CSS files?

Comment: Go to http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/drupal_process_attached/7 and search for 'External'.

Comment: Just a note - you can add JavaScript as described above to specific form by adding function named `<module name>_form_<form id>_alter` to your module. Finding form id is described here: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/5802/how-can-i-find-the-form-id-of-a-form

Comment: This example is kinda bad because you're assuming this will be the ONLY attachment on the form!

Comment: Comment by doublejosh means: usually one should append to the array rather than replacing it. So the example should be `$form['#attached']['css'][] = drupal_get_path('module', 'ajax_example') . '/ajax_example.css';` etc..

Comment: This answer REEEEEEAAAALLLLY needs updating.

Comment: You can put this code ($form['#attached']['css'][]= ...) for instance in a hook_form_FORM_ID_alter() function. https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_form_FORM_ID_alter/7.x

Answer (score 12):

Here's the method for adding *inline CSS* to forms...

```
$form['#attached']['css'][] = array(
  'data' => '.my-example-element { display: none; }',
  'type' => 'inline',
);
```

Note that you should *add* to the css array *rather than replace it*. Meaning you should use: `['css'][] =` rather than `['css'] =` to avoid squashing other additions.

Comment: This one no longer works and you get an error "LogicException: You are not allowed to use css in #attached".

Comment: Using D8? This answer was for D7.

Answer (score 6):

Here is one way to do this that is via. calling a function using `#after_build` property. Just pass in your form id in switch case.

```
function mymodule_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  switch ($form_id) {
    case 'my_form':
      $form['#after_build'][] = 'mymodule_after_build';
      break;
  }
}

function mymodule_after_build($form, &$form_state) {
  $path = drupal_get_path('module', 'mymodule');
  drupal_add_js ("$path/mymodule.js");
  return $form; 
}
```

Also you can follow this good tutorial [Adding css and js to drupal forms](http://www.jaypan.com/tutorial/adding-css-and-js-cached-block-drupal-7)

Hope this helps. :)

Comment: While this still works in Drupal 7, [it seems to be a D6 hack](https://www.drupal.org/node/1253520#comment-4881500), needed because [`#attached` did not exist in D6](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer%21topics%21forms_api_reference.html/6.x).

Comment: You should not use `drupal_add_js` on a form.  You'll end up with validation state trouble.

Comment: @doublejosh This is a three year old answer :)