# How can one add inline JavaScript in the validation function for the Form API?

Tags: 7, forms, javascript

I found that there is a way to add javascript files in the form validation function as stated in "[drupal_add_js not work in form validation failed](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/116612)".

However, I would like to know how to add javascript using the `drupal_add_js` function with the inline option. I would just like to execute some javascript code while I am in the validation function of the Drupal Form API.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See the docs @https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/api/javascript-api/managing-javascript-in-drupal-7

> **drupal_add_js() example:**
>
> ```
> drupal_add_js(
>   'jQuery(document).ready(function () { alert("Hello!"); });',
>   array(
>     'type' => 'inline',
>     'scope' => 'footer',
>     'group' => JS_THEME,
>     'weight' => 5,
>   )
> );
> ```
>
> **#attached example:**
>
> ```
> $element['#attached']['js'][] = array(
>   'type' => 'inline',
>   'data' => 'jQuery(document).ready(function () { alert("Hello!"); });',
>   'scope' => 'footer',
>   'group' => JS_THEME,
>   'weight' => 5,
> );
> ```

Just replace `$element` by `$form`.

---

Original source: https://web.archive.org/web/20160502205421/http://www.failover.co/snippets/drupal-7-attaching-css-and-javascript-forms-or-form-elements

Answer (score 0):

Use the `#attached` property to add your JS file instead of `drupal_add_js` function

More info: 
[FAPI #attached](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7#attached)

Comment: I am thinking that this is just what I will do, but I meant to ask if it is possible to use the inline option of the drupal_add_js function in this situation.