# How to include CSS for a custom admin theme?

Tags: theming, .info

I want to include my custom **style.css** in **admin pages** in Custom Admin theme I have been create.
I am including CSS in **.info** file as follows

```
name = Example Module
description = Custom Example Module
core = 7.x
configure = admin/config/example-module/settings
permissions = admin/people/permissions#module-example-module
stylesheets[all][] = css/style.css
```

and I used `mymodule_preprocess_page(&vars)` , but I didn't see any result.

Comment: why you try to load css from `.info` in custom module ??!!!!

Comment: @zhilevan Per https://www.drupal.org/node/542202, stylesheets is a valid directive in module.info files.  However, the practice isn't recommended.  CSS, JS, and libraries should use #attached in render arrays instead.

Comment: @MPD I know that but better way to add global css( that want be exist anywhere) is adding it in `themename.info` file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add **yourstyl.css** in admin theme's **.info** file.
Just goto your active admin theme, find and open its **.info** file and place a simple line here; **stylesheets[ ] = css/yourstyle.css** . It works like a charm.

Comment: But this is not a good idea if it's a core theme.

Comment: By using this method you are adding additional functionality to core theme. It's doesn't mean you are hacking core theme.

Comment: Well, it may get overwritten with the next update.

Comment: Just backup that file and add again after update.

Comment: It's getting complicated ;)

Comment: But in your question you said that you have "custom admin theme" .

Answer (score 1):

When I look at your `.info` file  I see it is **Custom Module** instead **Custom Theme**

```
name = Example Module
description = Custom Example Module
core = 7.x
configure = admin/config/example-module/settings
permissions = admin/people/permissions#module-example-module
stylesheets[all][] = css/style.css
```

Instead adding Style to **module info file** add it to **theme info file**
in your `themename.info` add `stylesheets[all][] = css/style.css`

Answer (score 0):

I misunderstood your question. It's not about a core admin theme. It's about a custom admin theme you created. Then of course you add that CSS from your custom admin theme's `.info` file.

Otherwise, if it's a core admin theme you'ld write a simple custom module or add the following to an existing custom module. All you need to implement is [`hook_page_build()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_page_build/7) and then add your own CSS file with [`drupal_add_css()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/drupal_add_css/7). The **important** thing there is to add `'group' => CSS_THEME` as an option to prevent the styles from getting overwritten.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_page_build().
 */
function MYMODULE_page_build(&$page) {
  // check current path
  if (path_is_admin(current_path())) {
    // add CSS
    drupal_add_css(drupal_get_path('module', 'MYMODULE') . '/css/custom_admin.css', array('group' => CSS_THEME));
  }
}
```

Comment: Your solution is good when he hasn't custom admin theme, when he created admin and has global CSS file ,  Do you thing is better to  load it from `themename.info` file instead with another way( like preprocess page or page build etc ) ?

Comment: Ah I see, @zhilevan. You are right. In this case you'ld do it from your `.info` file. Otherwise I think it's better to use a hook and `drupal_add_css()` since you have a lot of options available you don't have when you load it from a module's `.info` file

Comment: @leymanx I am agree with you ;)

Answer (score -2):

Try **[drupal_add_css()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/drupal_add_css/7)** function in your template file.

Comment: There is no template file. I am simply creating the form in admin pages and need to apply css for the same.
But unfortunately I am not able to do that.

Comment: How do you create this form?

Comment: Using hook_form in .module.
And mymodule is useful for different project, so cant edit theme template file manually. I need to apply css to form programatically when i access my admin page.

Comment: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/70015/adding-css-and-js-to-form-with-attachments

Comment: This is not solution, he had mistake in his code, instead add style in `theme.info` file added in `module.info` file