# How to add javascript after form was validated with ajax callback?

Tags: forms, ajax, javascript

I created a simple form.
How could I add JavaScript commands after form was validated? Why is it so hard do this?

```
$form['submit'] = array(
  '#type' => 'submit',
  '#value' => 'submit',
  '#validate' => 'my_validate_callback',
  '#ajax' => array(
    'callback' => 'my_form_callback',
    'method' => 'replace',
    'wrapper' => 'form-wrap',
    'effect' => 'fade'
  )
);
```

Comment: Could you be more descriptive of the problem. Why add js only after form is validated. What are you trying to do?

Comment: hello, i'm trying run a fancybox command when validate return some error, for open a div that it's a popup.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to add a JS file in validate or Ajax handler function you just need to add JS to form with [drupal_add_js](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_add_js/7) or [attach it to form](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/70015/adding-css-and-js-to-form-with-attachments).

This is an example of how can you add JavaScript in Ajax callback function:

```
function my_form_callback(&$form,$form_state){
if(some validation ){
$form['#attached']['js'] = array(
  drupal_get_path('module', 'ajax_example') . '/ajax_example.js',
);
}
return $form;
}
```

Comment: I want execute a javascript when validate callback return some errors and when all it's okay. if i use $form['#prefix'] = '<script>...</script'; ???