# Extending forms (or views, or something else?!)

Tags: javascript

If creating something like a form, but also perhaps any piece of front-end UI, what is the correct approach for adding things like extra Javascript (or HTML, or anything)?

I'm putting together a registration form using the [Entity Registration](https://www.drupal.org/project/registration) module and would like to know if, say, I wanted to have a 'Delivery address is the same as invoice address' checkbox that dynamically hid/revealed the delivery address part of the form, what would be the Drupal way of achieving that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could implement [hook_form_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7.x) for adding a checkbox field to your form.

The most simple thing to do after that is to handle the display of the form elements with JS/CSS (checked or not). You have to handle the validation of the different submissions of the form (with or without the delivery address part).

[Here](http://befused.com/drupal/form-validation) you can find a tutorial for adding custom validation to a form.

For the JS/CSS part, you can put your code in the main files of your theme, or add specific files for this form. Check [this](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/70015/adding-css-and-js-to-form-with-attachments#answer-70036) answer for the second solution.

Comment: Thanks for this, very helpful - is hook_form_alter the correct place to access $form['#attached']? I've added the function to my sub-theme's template.php, it seems to execute, but adding files to the $form['#attached']['css'] array, for example, doesn't seem to do anything. I can't tell from the docs if I'm doing the right thing though

Comment: Ok, got it working - not 100% sure template.php is the right place for this code, seems to work though. Thanks!