# Using #attached to attach js to form by a custom module

Tags: 7, forms

**My idea:**
I am trying to use a module to manage all the js and css with #attached method.
**`#attached` method I found from:**
- [Adding CSS and JS to form with attachments](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/70015/adding-css-and-js-to-form-with-attachments) 
- https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/api/javascript-api/managing-javascript-in-drupal-7

**My module folder containing:**
testing.info
testing.module
js/mask.js

**In testing.info**, it's including file testing.module
files[] = testing.module

**In testing.module**, I'm trying to use the #attached method to attach "jquery mask" to all form tags, including add/edit node, webform field.
 Here is my code but it does not work. -___-

```
function testing_init() {
  $build['#attached']['js']['https://cdn.testing.com/jquery.mask.min.js'] = array('type' => 'external');
  $form['#attached']['js'][] = drupal_get_path('module', 'testing') . '/js/mask.js';
}
```

**Question:**
Am I using the wrong method to attach js to form tag?
I don't want to load these files on all pages, what is the better way?

Comment: What [hook](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21module.inc/group/hooks/7.x) are you using?

Comment: @NoSssweat I'm using hook_init. it's function testing_init() { }

Comment: well `$form['#attached']['js'][] = drupal_get_path('module', 'testing') . '/js/mask.js';` is never going to work inside of hook_init. Use [hook_form_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7.x) `testing_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {` remember to flush cache after to see changes.

Comment: @NoSssweat it's workings :)

Comment: @NoSssweat is it possible only load for add/edit node and webform(not search form)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> @NoSssweat is it possible only load for add/edit node and webform(not
>   search form)? – CocoSkin

You can by utilizing [hook_form_BASE_FORM_ID_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_form_BASE_FORM_ID_alter/7.x)

For node's add/edit form:

```
/**
 *  Implements hook_form_BASE_FORM_ID_alter.
 */
function mymodule_form_node_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  $form['#attached']['js'][] = drupal_get_path('module', 'mymodule') . '/js/custom.js';
}
```

For Webform:

```
/**
 *  Implements hook_form_BASE_FORM_ID_alter.
 */
function mymodule_form_webform_client_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  $form['#attached']['js'][] = drupal_get_path('module', 'mymodule') . '/js/custom.js';
}
```