# Is there a way to alter output/markup for a field in node edit view?

Tags: 8

I am looking for a way to alter field output when rendered in the normal edit view.

I have looked at the [hook_quickedit_render_field](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21quickedit%21quickedit.api.php/function/hook_quickedit_render_field/) function which helps out in quick edit mode but are there something similar for the normal edit view? Drupal 8.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [hook_form_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Form%21form.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/8.4.x) or [hook_form_FORM_ID_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Form%21form.api.php/function/hook_form_FORM_ID_alter/8.4.x)

You'll need the ID to target specific forms; otherwise, you will endup altering every single form. See [How can I find the form ID of a form?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/5802/how-can-i-find-the-form-id-of-a-form)

Example of hook_form_FORM_ID_alter:

```
function mymodule_form_node_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  /* @var Drupal\Core\Entity\FieldableEntityInterface $node */
  $node = $form_state->getFormObject()->getEntity();

  if ($node->getType() == 'article') {
    // Alter the 'article' form here.
  }
}
```