# When creating a module, where do I set cookies?

Tags: 7

Drupal 7 newb here.

I am creating a simple module. Basically, this has an admin config form with a message text area. On the front end, that message appears or not depending on the state of a cookie.

My question is: where (in what function) should you set the cookie?

My code is:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_block_info().
 */
function message_block_info() {
  return [
    'message_block' => [
      'info' => t('Message'),
      'cache' => DRUPAL_CACHE_GLOBAL,
    ],
  ];
}

/**
 * Implements hook_theme().
 */
function message_theme() {
  return [
    'message_block' => [
      'template' => 'templates/message-block',
      'variables' => [
        'config' => NULL,
      ],
    ],
  ];
}

/**
 * Implements hook_block_view().
 */
function message_block_view($delta = '') {
  if ($delta !== 'message_block') {
    return;
  }

  $config = message_default_settings();
  if (empty($config['alert_message']) || $config['alert_show'] === 0) {
    return;
  }


  $block['content'] = array(
    '#theme' => 'message_block',
    '#config' => array(
      'alert_show' => $config['alert_show'],
      'alert_message' => filter_xss($config['alert_message']),
      'alert_link' => filter_xss($config['alert_link']),
    ),
  );

  return $block;
}
```

Comment: Depends on **when** do you want to set the cookie?

Comment: @NoSssweat as a newb, I honestly don't know. How do you ascertain that?

Comment: What is the cookie keeping track of? when (or what action) do you want that causes the cookie to be set?

Comment: I want the message to appear only once per user - so, if the user visits the site a 2nd time the message is no longer visible to them. I've also updated the above with my code.

Comment: Do you want once in forever? or its ok to show message again once cookie expires?

Comment: @NoSssweat that was the next part of my project - wanted to break it down. Ideally, I want to capture a timestamp of when the message was updated. If the user returns and the message has been updated, then it shows again. But like I said - I just want to learn how to show the message once first :)

Comment: You can set the cookie in [hook_form_FORM_ID_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_form_FORM_ID_alter/7.x). See [How can I find the form ID of a form?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/143963/27710) to get the FORM_ID

Answer (score 0):

Here i set the cookie as user login and logged out.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_user_login().
 */
function HOOK_user_login(&$edit, $account) {
  setcookie('user-logged-in', '2', 0, '/');
}

/**
 * Implements hook_user_logout().
 */
function HOOK_user_logout($account) {
  // Set cookie in the past and then remove it.
  setcookie('user-logged-in', '', REQUEST_TIME - 3600, '/');
  unset($_COOKIE['user-logged-in']);
}
```

You can try it will able to create new cookie anywhere i.e Create cookie into  hook_init() 
https://www.drupal.org/forum/support/theme-development/2009-05-26/setting-custom-cookies#comment-2901778

Comment: Ah sorry - should have said: the users are anonymous

Comment: Then you can also create cookie  into hook_init() function. https://www.drupal.org/forum/support/theme-development/2009-05-26/setting-custom-cookies#comment-2901778