# Change product price title in form

Tags: 8, commerce

How can I access the label of the product price field to change it for example to "amount" instead of "price"?

The html for the field is:

```
<div class="js-form-item form-item js-form-type-commerce-number form-item-variations-entity-price-0-number js-form-item-variations-entity-price-0-number">

<label for="edit-variations-entity-price-0-number" class="js-form-required form-required">Price</label>

<input data-drupal-selector="edit-variations-entity-price-0-number" type="text" id="edit-variations-entity-price-0-number" name="variations[entity][price][0][number]" value="" size="10" maxlength="128" class="form-text required" required="required">
```

I have tried various alternatives, but couldn't find a way to reach the title or the price field.

```
function THEME_form_alter(&$form, \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {
    $form['variations']['entity']['price'][0]['number']= t('Amount');
    $form['variations']['entity']['price']['number']= t('Amount');
    $form['price']= t('Amount');
}
```

I also couldn't find any examples to use form_alter on Drupal 8 Commerce product form while it was possible with Drupal 7.

Comment: You need to use `hook_form_alter()` on the correct form ID.  So the first step is to find the **form ID**, and then use that to dump the form and figure out what you need to change.  See https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/5802/how-can-i-find-the-form-id-of-a-form

Comment: Form ID= "commerce_product_default_add_form". Where to go from here?

Comment: Install the Devel module (not on production!) and use Kint.  Then you can do something like `kint($form)` to get a somewhat pretty list of all the variables.  https://www.drupaleasy.com/quicktips/drupal-8-debugging-kareful-klicking-kint

Comment: This doesn't work: 

`function THEME_commerce_product_default_add_form_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {dpm($form_id); }`

Comment: This seems to work:
`function THEME_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id == 'commerce_product_default_add_form') {dpm($form); }
}`

Comment: It would be `THEME_form_commerce_product_default_add_form_alter` for the more specific hook - you had the first `form_` part at the end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$form['variations']['widget']['entity']['price']['widget'][0]['#title'] = t('Amount');
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed!