# Why is this hook implementation not working?

Tags: hooks, files

I am new to custom modules and hooks and i am trying to connect to a sharepoint site i created to upload pictures of a content i have into sharepoint instead of drupal's file system. My issue is not actually with all this, the initial function sharepoint_file_upload_form_alter isn't working. I added the die(); function to test if the function is being called but i was able to add content normally. I made sure the names of the content types and then the name of the function and module are the same so i have no idea what else to check. Can anyone help please? Thank you.

```
<?php

use Symfony\Component\HttpClient\HttpClient;

/**
 * Implements hook_form_alter().
 */
function sharepoint_file_upload_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id == 'album_photo_evenements_node_form') {
    die();
    $form['field_images_album']['#element_validate'][] = 'sharepoint_file_upload_image_upload_validate';
  }
}

function sharepoint_file_upload_image_upload_validate($element, &$form_state, $form) {
  // Loop through each file uploaded in the field_images_album field.
  foreach ($element['#value'] as $key => $value) {
    if (!empty($value['fid'])) {
      $file = file_load($value['fid']);
      if ($file) {
        // Get the file contents.
        $file_contents = file_get_contents($file->getFileUri());

        // Upload the file to SharePoint.
        $url = upload_file_to_sharepoint($file->getFilename(), $file_contents);

        if ($url) {
          // Save the file URL to the field_images_album field.
          $form_state['values']['field_images_album'][LANGUAGE_NONE][$key]['value'] = $url;
        }
        else {
          drupal_set_message(t('Error uploading file to SharePoint.'), 'error');
        }

        // Delete the uploaded file.
        file_delete($file);
      }
      else {
        drupal_set_message(t('Error loading file.'), 'error');
      }
    }
  }
}

/**
 * Uploads a file to SharePoint.
 */
function upload_file_to_sharepoint($file_name, $file_contents) {
  // Get the SharePoint authentication token.
  $digest_value = get_sharepoint_auth_token();

  if ($digest_value) {
    // Set the SharePoint REST API endpoint.
    $url = "https://testusjedu.sharepoint.com/sites/usjnet_Production/_api/web/Lists(guid'4a3b0d0c-0ec0-40f2-89db-e355a778f639')/Items";

    // Set the necessary headers.
    $headers = [
        'Authorization' => 'Bearer ' . $digest_value,
        'Accept' => 'application/json;odata=verbose',
        'Content-Type' => 'application/json;odata=verbose',
    ];

    // Set the request payload.
    $payload = [
        'Title' => 'New Image',
        'Image' => [
            '__metadata' => [
                'type' => 'SP.FieldUrlValue',
            ],
            'Description' => 'Image description',
            'Url' => '',
        ],
    ];

    // Make the request to SharePoint.
    $client = HttpClient::create();
    $response = $client->request('POST', $url, [
        'headers' => $headers,
        'json' => $payload,
    ]);

    if ($response->getStatusCode() == 201) {
        $responseData = json_decode($response->getContent(), true);
        $uploadedImageUrl = $responseData['d']['Url'];
        return $uploadedImageUrl;
    } else {
        return FALSE;
    }
  }
  else {
    return FALSE;
  }
}

/**
 * Gets the SharePoint authentication token.
 */
function get_sharepoint_auth_token() {
  // Replace these values with your actual Azure app and SharePoint details
  $clientId = '#######';
  $clientSecret = '#######';
  $tenantId = '########';
  $resource = "https://testusjedu.sharepoint.com/sites/usjnet_Production/_api/web/Lists(guid'4a3b0d0c-0ec0-40f2-89db-e355a778f639')/Items"; // SharePoint site URL or API endpoint URL

  $tokenEndpoint = sprintf('https://login.microsoftonline.com/%s/oauth2/token', $tenantId);

  $client = HttpClient::create();

  $response = $client->request('POST', $tokenEndpoint, [
    'body' => [
        'grant_type' => 'client_credentials',
        'client_id' => $clientId,
        'client_secret' => $clientSecret,
        'resource' => $resource,
    ],
  ]);

  $content = $response->getContent();
  $accessToken = json_decode($content, true)['access_token'];

  return $accessToken;
}
```

Comment: What is the name of the module’s info.yml file? Did you rebuild caches after introducing the hooks? Is the module installed?

Comment: Hello, yes all the above has been done. Module name is sharepoint_file_upload(Folder name, .info.yml file name and .module file name are all the same)

Comment: It is necessary to interview you because there is not enough information in the question to provide a factual answer. Are you certain `album_photo_evenements_node_form` is the correct form identifier?

Comment: The content type has machine name album_photo_evenements
As per google aqnd chat gpt the form id is the machine name with _node_form at the end. is this correct?

Comment: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/5802/how-can-i-find-the-form-id-of-a-form

Comment: Thank you, turned out the id should be node_album_photo_evenements_form and that's why it wasn't working. Thank you for your help.